# Design and SEO for a single page dynamic website with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, seo, sitedesign

I designed a website in which the whole site is contained within one page (index.php).
Within the page, `<section>` tags define different parts of the site (home, contact, blog etc.)

Navigation is achieved by buttons that are always visible, and when clicked use javascript to change the visibility of the sections, so that only one is shown at any time.

More specifically, this is done by using the hash in the url, and handling the `hashchange` event. This results in urls such as www.site.com/#home (the default if no other hash is present) and www.site.com/#contact.

I want to know if this is a good design. It works, but I get the feeling there must be a better way to achieve the same thing? To clarify, I was aiming for site that loaded all the main content once, so that there were no more page loads after the initial load, and moving between sections would be smoother.

On top of this, another problem is introduced concerning SEO. The site shows up in google, but if for example, a search query contains a term in a specific section, it still loads the default #home page when clicked, not the specific section the term was found in. How can I rectify this?

Finally, one of the sections is a blog section, which is the only section that does not load all at once, since by default it loads the latest post from a database. When a user selects a different post from a list (which in itself is loaded using AJAX), AJAX is used to fetch and display the new post, and pushState changes the history. Again, to give each post a unique url that can be referenced externally, the menu changes the url which is handled by javascript, resulting in urls such as `www.site.com/?blogPost=2#blog` and `www.site.com/?blogPost=1#blog`.

These posts aren't seen by google at all. Using the Googlebot tool shows that the crawler sees the blog section as always empty, so none of the blog posts are indexed.

What can I change?

(I don't know if this should be on the webmasters stackexchange, so sorry if its in the wrong place)

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you need to post this on webmaster exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a normal site. Give each page a normal URL. Let Google index those URLs. If you don't have pages for Google to index, that it can't index your content.

Progressively enhance the site with JS/Ajax.

When a link is followed (or other action that, without JS, would load a new page is performed) use JavaScript to transform the current page into the target page.

Use [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) to change the URL to the URL that would have been loaded if you were not using JavaScript. (Do this instead of using the fragment identifer (`#`) hack).

Make sure you [listen for history events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_popstate_event) so you can transform the page back when the back button is clicked.

This results in situations such as:

1. User arrives at `/foo` from Google
2. `/foo` contains all the content for the `/foo` page
3. User clicks link to `/bar`
4. JavaScript changes the content of the page to match what the user would have got from going to `/bar` directly and sets URL to `/bar` with `pushState`

---

Note that there is also the ([not recommended](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)) hashbang technique which hacks a one-page site into a form that Google can index, but which is not robust, doesn't work for any other non-JS client and is almost as much work as doing things properly.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. So, you say to split the sections (home, contact, blog) into their own html pages (complete with CSS/standalone) as in a normal website, and link them together using the menu. This would be index-able by the crawler. How can JS be used to "transform" one whole page into another, without loading the new page, which is what I was trying to avoid? How would the blog then fit into this architecture?

Comment: How is the JS transforming the pages now? Same way. The blog would fit in just like any other set of pages.

Comment: I see, the difference I don't get is that that currently all the pages content is loaded at one, then hidden and shown as required, meaning no more requests to the server, its all done locally as i wanted. In the way you propose, wouldn't navigating to a different page by any means cause a request to the server, which I don't want. Take this site i just found as an example: http://www.vissio.ro/ here the individual sections scroll, instead of switching between each other, but the idea is the same, and doesn't seem to use pages? Thanks for the advice btw!

Comment: You said you were using Ajax. If you aren't loading the content on demand, but are just showing and hiding it, then you aren't using Ajax. I can't think of a sensible way to make that style of page index nicely for search engines (since they won't index via fragment ids, but fragment ids are the only way you could describe which bit of the page to view)

Comment: ahh, sorry for the confusion. The actual site layout and sections are not ajax. There are, as you say, showing and hiding parts of the same page. The only part that is ajax is the content within the blog section, which fetches the list of blog posts to choose from, and the content of the latest one when the blog nav button is clicked.
It seems that this structure is just not good enough, mainly for the blog indexing. I will have to look into another way.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. My updated solution has removed hashes entirely. Navigation is done using a query string, with javascript using pushState and onPopState to manage the history stack. What is displayed is still controlled by javascript, but I hope that now that I have URLs with just query strings i'll be able to use htaccess to rewrite these to paths. I think this will be less of a problem for search engine bots?